# Python data manipulation for unusual data format

Tags: python, csv, data-files

I've been trying to figure out how to manipulate this slightly unusually formatted data into a plottable format using just python (I'd been doing in with a shell script using sed and the like, but I want to be doing all my scripting in python longterm as that's what I usually use).

My data looks like this:

```
# Title of File
# step number_of_slices total_a
# slice Coord N v
51000 5 240000
  1 0.025 12003 0.0255628 
  2 0.075 11991 0.0257368
  3 0.125 11989 0.0258158
  4 0.175 11997.2 0.0259262
  5 0.225 11995.8 0.0258637
52000 5 240000
  1 0.025 12004.7 0.0251662
  2 0.075 11998.7 0.0256496
  3 0.125 11996.3 0.025816
  4 0.175 11994 0.0259593
  5 0.225 12008.3 0.0258245
  .
  .
  .
1010000 5 240000                                                                                                   
  1 0.025 12304.6 0.0182998                                                                                                     
  2 0.075 12146.1 0.0195533                                                                                         
  3 0.125 12026.9 0.0211158                                                                                         
  4 0.175 12003.5 0.0228836                                                                                         
  5 0.225 12000.3 0.0242854
```

And I want the data from just the fourth column appended to a single file for each 'step', i.e.

```
Steps 51000 52000 ... 1010000
1 0.0255628 0.0251662 ... 0.0182998
2 0.0257368 0.025816 ... 0.0195533
3 0.0258158 0.0259593 ... 0.0211158
4 0.0259262 0.0258245 ... 0.0228836
5 0.0258637 0.0258245 ... 0.0242854
```

In bash this was pretty easy. I cut the fourth column of every 6 lines and appended to a new file. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with just python.

This is the best I got:

```
import csv

f = open('file.dat')
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter = " ")

column = []

for row in csv_f:
        column.append(row[5])
print column

f.close()
```

The 5 is because I end up with the first two columns empty (I guess that's a formatting thing) but because some rows have only 3 elements this gives me an error so I can't even isolate the column in order to begin to get the format I want:

```
['51000', '20', '240000']
['', '', '1', '0.025', '12003', '0.0255628']
['', '', '2', '0.075', '11991', '0.0257368']
['', '', '3', '0.125', '11989', '0.0258158']
['', '', '4', '0.175', '11997.2', '0.0259262']
['', '', '5', '0.225', '11995.8', '0.0258637']
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "open.py", line 13, in 
column.append(row[5])
IndexError: list index out of range

At this point, I think I've overcomplicated it, and any solution I come up with will be quite convoluted instead of streamlining my workflow as intended. What's the 'correct' way? Please and thank you

Comment: don't used csv. just iterate over lines in the file and parse each line - check if it starts with space or not. split at spaces. depending on what row starts with - take the element you want. It's unclear about the first 3 rows - do they present in the file?

Comment: If steps are always 5 - you can use it instead of checking what line starts with

Answer (score 1):

Simply "chunk" your input in packets of 6 lines.  File the data in parallel lists.
Don't even bother with the CSV reader; you don't need the structure.

```
step = []
value = [[] for _ in range(5)]  # initialize 5 value lists

with open('file.dat') as f:
    for _ in range(num_of_header_lines):
        f.readline()

    while # not f.EOF
        # extract step: first value on the line
        step.append(int(f.readline().split()[0]))
        for phase in range(5):
            # Extract the last value for the appropriate phase list
            value[phase].append(float(f.readline().split()[-1]))
```

I've left the file initialization and EOF details for you -- this is the internal logic.
You grab a line and append the step number to the step list.  Then you read five more lines, grabbing the last value off each line for its corresponding sub-list.

Comment: you definitely want to use `.readline()` not `.read()` method. or just iterate over `f` and process the lines.

Comment: In lines 4-6 are you restarting the reading until you pass the header? I think I get that.

Comment: I'm afraid for the latter half I'm still stuck. First Q, is it split(0) not split[0]? (sorry!) And I don't understand what you mean by a phase list.

Comment: Yes, those three lines are to skip the header.  The second half looks better, thanks to @buran spotting my `read` error, and you noticing the `split` problem.  We want to `split` the input line, index the *one* desired field, and convert that to numeric.